# How to get the difference between ngrx states after another action completes?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is there any way to find out how can I get the difference between previous and current state in ngrx.

This would be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have previousValue and currentValue for each thing that you care about in the store. When you update the reducer you can set the previousValue to the currentValue and set currentValue to the new value you just got

Comment: So I get your point but I want to check which variables were changed after another action completes? just like in redux dev tool

Comment: see ```distinct until changed```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684733/how-to-access-previous-state-and-current-state-and-compare-them-when-you-subscri

Answer (score 2):

I personally use a select, like

```
let state = store.select(['reducer', 'state']);
```

and subscribe to the state change

```
state.takeLast(2).subscribe((result: any[]) => {
  for (let x of result) {
    if (result[x - 1] && (result[x] someCondition result[x - 1])){
      doSomething
    }
  }
})
```

then just do your simple conditional stuff and viola!

rxjs operators are plentiful and are awesome (like  [last()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html) or [takeLast()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takelast.html) for instance)

EDIT just noticed the question and title are a bit different. But you can basically if you dispatch to a state that is used for different actions, the pub/sub method above will still work