# How to access previous state and current state and compare them when you subscribe to store in ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

In my component I subscribe to ngrx store which is triggered on change in the given state. I want to set the condition that if current and previous states are different then I do some action.

How to get previous state?

```
    this.store
      .select('testPortfolio')
      .subscribe(testPortfolio => {
        // if(testPortfolio.oldValue !== testPortfolio.currentValueValue) ??? ///something like this
        console.log(testPortfolio);
       });
```

Comment: When you subscribe can you check if you get two values by default? .subscribe(newValue, oldValue) => {...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [distinctuntilchanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) for that. In your case it will be something like:

```js
this.store
  .pipe(
    select('testPortfolio'),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.value === curr.value)
  )
  .subscribe(testPortfolio => {
    console.log(testPortfolio); // called only when testPortfolio value has been changed
  });
```

Comment: What kind of behavior do you have in your implementation? Could you please show your code?

Comment: Since `select('testPortfolio')` could be returning an object from a different location in memory, doing a triple `===` comparator on the `distinctUntilChanged` is not enough because it will never be satisfied. Try doing `distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b))`.

Comment: if u want to dispatch the action after if state changes then `distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.value !== curr.value)` will work.