# how to solve this endless loop when selecting a store slice in init hook?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

When instantiating a component I need to dispatch an action with a series of props that will be handled by an effect that will in turn obtain data. After this operation I need to update the state and save the criteria of this search. Doing the last thing I understand causes an endless loop

*Update 0*

I found this question [How to access previous state and current state and compare them when you subscribe to store in ngrx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59684733/how-to-access-previous-state-and-current-state-and-compare-them-when-you-subscri), its suggested to use `distinctUntilChanged` In order to only dispatch the action on the component instantiation I use `distinctUntilChanged` . When changing the values of `startDate` or `endDate` I expect it to be executed but this does not happen, it simply does not execute. Any idea?

```
this.store
  .pipe(
    select('dashboard'),
    distinctUntilChanged(
      (prev, curr) =>
        prev.startDate === curr.startDate || prev.endDate === curr.endDate
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (state) => {
      this.startDate = state.startDate;
      this.endDate = state.endDate;
      // ...


      this.store.dispatch(
        filter({
          startDate: this.startDate,
          endDate: this.endDate
        })
      );
    },
  });
```

component class

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.select('dashboard').subscribe({
    next: (state) => {
      this.startDate = state.startDate;
      this.endDate = state.endDate;
      // ...

      this.store.dispatch(
        filter({
          startDate: this.startDate,
          endDate: this.endDate,
        })
      );
    },
  });
}
```

action

```
export const filter = createAction(
  '[Dashboard component] Apply filter',
  props<{
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
  }>()
);
```

effect look similar to this

```
filter$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(filter),
    switchMap((action) => {
      const obs0$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        // ...
      });

      const obs1$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        // ...
      });

      const obs2$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        // ...
      });

      const obs3$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
          // ...
        }
      );

      const obs4$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        // ...
      });

      const obs5$ = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
        // ...
      });

      return forkJoin<readonly SourceModel[] | readonly RankingModel[]>([
        obs1$,
        obs2$,
        obs3$,
        obs4$,
        obs5$,
        obs6$,
      ]).pipe(map((response) => filterSuccess({ payload: response })));
    })
  )
);
```

reducer look similar to this

```
// ...

export interface AdminState {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
}

export const initialState: AdminState = {
  startDate: new Date(),
  endDate: getDashboardFilterDefaultEndDate(),
};

export const adminReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(filter, (state, { startDate, endDate }) => ({
    ...state,
    startDate,
    endDate,
  })),
  on(filterSuccess, (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    // ...
  }))
);
```

I understand that the behavior is due to the fact that when the data collection is complete and the search criteria are updated in the reducer, the select in the init of the component triggers a new search. If so, how can I handle this?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: Are you sure you need to update the `startDate` and `endDate` in your `filter` action? What do you change in the state for your action `filterSuccess`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the way you consume the state.

You have to create selectors that are only triggered when the value is actually changed and if you do so, you won't have to use the `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

Comment: Thanks for answering, sadly the problem persist